# Google calender integration using PHP in the website

Tags: php, integration, google-calendar-api

I am new to google calender. I need to integrate google calender in the website (like listing,adding,editing and deleting events). How can I do this ??

Please help me to do google calender integration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google provides code for you to do this. You can read up on it at
https://support.google.com/calendar/topic/1672470?hl=en&ref_topic=1665165

Hope this helps.